# mipsel-linux-gnu-as fails to fill delay slot

Tags: assembly, mips, gnu-assembler

I have the following compiler:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 12.2.0
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And I give its assembler the following input:

```
.global __start
__start:
        lw $10,array
        lw $11,array+4
        add $12, $10, $11
        sw $12,array+8
        j __start
array:
    .word 1
    .word 2
    .word 0
```

Then we assemble and link:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-as -mips2 asm/start.asm -o obj/start.asm.o 
mipsel-linux-gnu-ld -o final obj/start.asm.o  -Tlinker_script.ld
```

For completeness, here is the linker script:

```
MEMORY
{
    SRAM (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x100000, LENGTH = 0x60000
}

SECTIONS
{
    .text :
    {
        *(.text)
    } > SRAM

    .data : 
    {
        *(.data)
    } > SRAM

    .bss : 
    {
        *(.data)
    } > SRAM
}
```

Now, if I look at the .text section of my linked program via objdump, I see:

```
mipsel-linux-gnu-objdump -j .text -D final          

final:     file format elf32-tradlittlemips


Disassembly of section .text:

00100000 <__start>:
  100000:       3c0a0010        lui     t2,0x10
  100004:       8d4a0024        lw      t2,36(t2)
  100008:       3c0b0010        lui     t3,0x10
  10000c:       8d6b0028        lw      t3,40(t3)
  100010:       014b6020        add     t4,t2,t3
  100014:       3c010010        lui     at,0x10
  100018:       ac2c002c        sw      t4,44(at)
  10001c:       08040000        j       100000 <__start>
  100020:       00000000        nop

00100024 <array>:
  100024:       00000001        0x1
  100028:       00000002        srl     zero,zero,0x0
  10002c:       00000000        nop
```

Here we can see that the assembler puts a nop in the delay slot of the jump instruction. And I fail to understand why, it seems to me that `sw      t4,44(at)` can be put in there? Is this a limitation of pseudoinstructions, or am I wrong in thinking that the `sw` could be put in the delay slot?

Comment: Looks like missed optimization. Notice that the assembler had to generate extra `lui` to `$at` for your `sw` and apparently that inhibits the delay slot fill. A "real" `sw` will be placed in the delay slot.